# How to develop custom fields for SharePoint Online list - Lookup with Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint 2010 list where a custom field "Lookup with Picker" has been implemented through a farm solution. We need to migrate the list to SharePoint Online but since we cannot deploy farm solutions in O365 environment, is there a alternative or workaround to implement that custom field in SP Online?

More Details: The custom field helps to lookup on large lists using "user picker" type of search functionality. Please refer to this [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=lookupwithpicker) for details of how the field behaves in current on-premise environment

Comment: What does this custom field do? Could you please explain and add some more details about the requirement?

Comment: the custom field helps to lookup on large lists using "user picker" type of search functionality. Please refer to this [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=lookupwithpicker) for details of how the field behaves in current on-premise environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your fundamental problem is due to **lookup in a large list**. Right now,the options are to use custom add/edit form in your list and use jQuery to create your custom look up solution (if you are using SharePoint designer and ok with classic pages), or you can try to achieve the same using PowerApps, which works with SharePoint modern pages.

Also, please make sure to apply appropriate indexes in your large look up list, else, you won't be able to query it.

Note: If the list is stored else where, like in a Azure SQL server table, then you can use BCS to achieve the same thing and there you will have search by default. This will take less effort.

Comment: Thanks for the response and guidance @UBK . Powerapps is not available in our company yet. So the only solution is to make custom forms in Designer and yes classic experience is acceptable. But I am not sure how to implement search window as shown in the example link I mentioned above. Can you give me some code snippet, guidance or point me to any online resources

Comment: @SoumyorupDey here are the basics, I'm sure you will find appropriate examples by Googling. There should be a button to open the search popup, which can be a visibility hidden DIV in your page. Upon search, it will call SharePoint REST api to filter the lookup list and show the results in a grid/ table in side the popup and you need to implement a call back to that once they select one/ more items it will send the value back to your list add/edit form. Now, you can either use SharePoint REST api to filter the list or SharePoint Search REST Api.

Comment: Thank you so much @UBK......this was all I was looking for.....I was not able to figure out how to approach....thanks for the guidance